# list filenames with highest number in name bash

Tags: bash

Imagine I'm having a directory listing of files with names like so:

- 0006_0001.txt
- 0006_0002.txt
- 0006_0003.txt
- 0006_0004.txt
- 0007_0001.txt
- 0008_0001.txt
- 0008_0002.txt
- 0009_0004.txt
- 0010_0002.txt

...

- 0808_0001.txt
- 0808_0005.txt

The pattern is always the same, I would like to select the files with the highest last number in the name. So in this case above for example the result should be:

- 0006_0004.txt
- 0007_0001.txt
- 0008_0002.txt
- 0009_0004.txt
- 0010_0002.txt
- 0808_0005.txt

I was experimenting with something like:

```
find . -name '*_000[1-9].AHF' | sed 's/\([0-9]_[0-9].AHF\+\).*/\1/g' | sort -n
```

But it isn't right, I guess in principle with ls it should be possible with some sed?

Thanks

Comment: Are you searching files recursively?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have file names in a file, this will make it:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="_"} {a[$1]=(a[$1]<$2?$2:a[$1])} END {for (i in a) print i,a[i]}' file
```

Otherwise, just pipe the list:

```
your_find_command | awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="_"} {a[$1]=(a[$1]<$2?$2:a[$1])} END {for (i in a) print i,a[i]}'
```

#### Explanation

- `BEGIN{FS=OFS="_"}` set input and output field separator as `_`.
- `{a[$1]=(a[$1]<$2?$2:a[$1])}` store the maximum of 2nd block, being 1nd block the index for the array.
- `END {for (i in a) print i,a[i]}` prints the [hopefully] desired output.

#### Test

```
$ cat a
0006_0001.txt
0006_0002.txt
0006_0003.txt
0006_0004.txt
0007_0001.txt
0008_0001.txt
0008_0002.txt
0009_0004.txt
0010_0002.txt
0808_0001.txt
0808_0005.txt

$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="_"} {a[$1]=(a[$1]<$2?$2:a[$1])} END {for (i in a) print i,a[i]}' a
0808_0005.txt
0006_0004.txt
0007_0001.txt
0008_0002.txt
0009_0004.txt
0010_0002.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just:

- Sort by reverse order to have bigger numbers on top (`sort -r`)
- Remove the duplicates checking only the first 4 characters (`uniq -w4`)
- Reverse the order of the lines if you need them in the exact order (`tac`)

So the command will be:

```
your command | sort -r | uniq -w4 | tac
```

A more eloquent version would be (the benefit of using it is that you can *read* what they do):

```
your command | sort --reverse | uniq --check-chars=4 | tac
```

### Example

```
$ cat FILE
0006_0001.txt
0006_0002.txt
0006_0003.txt
0006_0004.txt
0007_0001.txt
0008_0001.txt
0008_0002.txt
0009_0004.txt
0010_0002.txt
0808_0001.txt
0808_0005.txt

$ cat FILE | sort -r | uniq -w4
0808_0005.txt
0010_0002.txt
0009_0004.txt
0008_0002.txt
0007_0001.txt
0006_0004.txt

$ cat FILE | sort -r | uniq -w4 | tac
0006_0004.txt
0007_0001.txt
0008_0002.txt
0009_0004.txt
0010_0002.txt
0808_0005.txt
```

Comment: very nice. I like this answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you (assuming the files end in `.txt` - your names do, but your code assumes the ending is `.AHF`):

```
find . -name '*_000[1-9].txt' | grep -oE '[0-9]+_[0-9]+' | sort -t _ -k 2nr
```

Your `sed` command was incorrect because you didn't match more than one digit on either side of the `_`.  However, the `grep` is slightly more clear - the `-o` says just output the match, rather than the whole line.

The above command will print the line with the highest second number first; it then sorts increasing by the first number. If you desire both to be decreasing, use `sort -t _ -k 2,1n -r` .

Of course, this won't get you the actual filenames; just the numerical portions.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN {
    FS = "[_.]"
}
{
    t = $0
    sub(/.*\//, "")
    sub(/^0+/, "", $1)
    sub(/^0+/, "", $2)
    if ($1 in a) {
        if ($2 > b[$1]) {
            a[$1] = t
            b[$1] = $2
        }
    } else {
        keys[++k] = $1
        a[$1] = t
        b[$1] = $2
    }
}
END {
    for (i = 1; i <= k; ++i)
        print a[keys[i]]
}
```

Usage:

```
find . -name '*_000[1-9].AHF' | awk -f script.awk
```

Test Input:

```
./0006_0001.txt
./0006_0002.txt
./0006_0003.txt
./0006_0004.txt
./0007_0001.txt
./0008_0001.txt
./0008_0002.txt
./0009_0004.txt
./0010_0002.txt
./0808_0001.txt
./0808_0005.txt
```

Output:

```
$ awk -f script.awk < input
./0006_0004.txt
./0007_0001.txt
./0008_0002.txt
./0009_0004.txt
./0010_0002.txt
./0808_0005.txt
```

The script also applies recursively.